# Tools to capture state of a html 5/css 3 page so visual designer can make changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

New to working with web UI.  We have a complicated setup that takes code and generates resulting HTML 5 and CSS 3 with a bunch of javascript.  I need to be able to capture the resulting HTML/CSS after taking the UI through a couple of workflows (that kick off a bunch of javascript DOM changes that I don't understand) so that I can work with my designer to tweak the layout and give back to the devs to change.

Is there a way to do this?  I was able to copy the HTML from firebug but it still had references to the CSS on the server and there wasn't an easy way to download the CSS and update the HTML to point to them locally.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the following page will create a download link when you paste copied HTML into the box using firefox or chrome.

```
<html>

<b>Select All, Copy, and paste below to download the full copied HTML</b>

<div id=drop contentEditable 
  style="padding: 1em; height: 30em; background:#bbb;overflow:hidden; ">
</div>

<a id=out download=copied.html style=display:none> Download </a>

<script>

var out=document.getElementById("out"), 
   drop=document.getElementById("drop");


drop.onpaste=function doPaste(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        out.href="data:x-application/html,"+
          escape(drop.innerHTML);
        drop.style.display="none";
        out.style.display="block";
    }, 50);
};

</script>
</html>
```

to use with your site,

1. do stuff to make page change, then click an empty area of the page background and 
   press [CTRL]+[A] (win) or [CMD]+[A] (mac)
2. copy using right-click or keyboard
3. paste into the box in the file shown above
4. click "download" to download the resulting html file.

since it's a tiny file, i went ahead and threw [a copy online](http://danml.com/paste.html) so you can try it out; works pretty well for this page.

note that style info is converted to style attribs, so you don't need the css files, but at the same time, you don't have the filenames of the applied style, which some designers might want...